# Letter from Ilya

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I vaguely recall reading a humorous short story with a title like "A Letter From Ilya" about an alien creature who sneaks onto a human spaceship and describes what he finds to a friend.

One of the things the alien finds on the ship is soup, or maybe stew.

I thought it was funny fifty years ago and would love to see if it still is.

Comment: Can you add *any* more details? Anything at all?

Comment: I think one of the things the alien found on the ship was soup, or maybe stew. I wish I could remember more. Sorry.

Comment: You might look over the titles containing the phrase "letter from" at ISFDB... only so many would be old enough to qualify. See http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=letter+from&type=Fiction+Titles

Comment: I remember this too, I recall he lived the human beans music! Lol gear sorry, sure it was in a collection of short stories

Comment: Looks like someone else is looking for the same story: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179401/short-story-told-from-vegetarian-aliens-pov-observing-astronaut-behavior-inclu

Answer (score 6):

**The title of the story is "[Good-Bye, Ilha!](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57972)" and it was written by Laurence Manning.**

I finally found it, thanks to the [Index to Science Fiction Anthologies and Collections, Combined Edition](http://www.philsp.com/homeville/isfac/0start.htm), by William G. Contento. It was published in the following:

- Good-Bye, Ilha!, (ss) Beyond Human Ken, ed. Judith Merril, Random 1952
- Beyond Human Ken, ed. Judith Merril, Grayson 1953
- Selections from Beyond Human Ken, ed. Judith Merril, Pennant 1954
- Giants Unleashed, ed. Groff Conklin, Grosset & Dunlap 1965